# a simple typographical error in .c

Tags: c, debugging, divide-by-zero

i was just writing a program to change a decimal number to another base(2<=radix<=16).
 after running the program and printing the correct answer, I encountered an error that reads : "program has stopped working" . could you please take a look at my code and find where it dangles???!!! i am really confused.
this is my code:

```
int decimal, radix, pow = 1, temp;
printf("enter your number and the 2 <= radix <= 16\n");
scanf("%d%d",&decimal, &radix);
temp = decimal;
for(; temp >= radix; temp /= radix)// finding the greatest exponent of radix in decimal
    pow *= radix;
while(pow >= 1){
    decimal -= temp * pow;
    if(temp == 10)
        printf("A");
    else if(temp == 11)
        printf("B");
    else if(temp == 12)
        printf("C");
    else if(temp == 13)
        printf("D");
    else if(temp == 14)
        printf("E");
    else if(temp == 15)
        printf("F");
    else
        printf("%d",temp);
    pow /= radix;
    temp = decimal / pow;
}
puts("");
```

i think the problem is because of "temp = decimal / pow" but how can I fix it??

Comment: There is simpler way to convert a decimal to another base. Here check if you are dividing  `decimal` when `pow=0`.

Comment: The problem is **division by zero** on on the last line of the loop.

Comment: I.e. the last division of `pow /= radix` results in `pow` being floored to *0*, and `temp = decimal / pow` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then **use the debugger `gdb`**

Comment: Tnx for mentioning I changed the title. And about the simpler way can you show it to me if it does not include any arrays??  Because my solution was supposed to be a non_array one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `pow` is 0 when you are calculating `temp = decimal / pow;` at the end of `while` loop

```
    pow /= radix;
    if (pow > 0)
    {
        temp = decimal / pow;
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much . Yeah division by zero also stroke my mind but I couldn't find where it equals to zero. Afterall , it is very hard to debug your own program.